# Factor a large number efficiently with gmp

Tags: c++, math, primes, gmp, factorization

I need to get all the prime factors of large numbers that can easily get to 1k bits.
The numbers are practically random so it shouldn't be hard.
How do I do it efficiently? I use C++ with GMP library.

EDIT:
I guess you all misunderstood me.
What I mean by prime a number is to get all prime factors of the number.
Sorry for my english, in my language prime and factor are the same :)

---

clarification (from OP's other post):

What I need is a way to efficiently factor(find prime factors of a number) large numbers(may get to 2048 bits) using C++ and GMP(Gnu Multiple Precession lib) or less preferably any other way.
The numbers are practically random so there is little chance it will be hard to factor, and even if the number is hard to factor, I can re-roll the number(can't choose though).

Comment: What do you mean by prime in this context? Are you trying to generate large prime numbers? Or do you mean prepare the numbers ahead of time for some particular use?

Comment: You push the little squishy button on the side of the number to bump it up a few notches, so it's prime and the engine starts running smoothly.

Comment: I agree, the english on this is bad enough that I can guess what the OP meant, but it certainly isn't clear.

Comment: The probability of the hard case of composite numbers with two prime factors is not negligible IMHO (my quick estimation gives on the order of 1 in 100000 random numbers with 1024 bits).

Comment: @starblue: Interesting! could you explain your math in more detail?

Comment: Basically I use that there are about `n/log n` primes among the first `n` numbers to approximate the number of 512 bit primes. The square is approximately the number of hard pairs with 1024 bits (most of these primes have close to 512 bits).

Comment: Note that this just estimates a lower bound for the case of being practically impossible to factor. There are many more numbers which may still be too hard to factor quickly.

Comment: BTW, why do you need to factor these numbers?

Answer (score 11):

A good start would be some pre-filtering with small primes, say about all primes lower than 100 000 or so. Simply try to divide by every single one of them (create a table which you then load at runtime or have it as static data in your code). It might seem slow and stupid, but if the number is totally random, this will give you some factors very fast with a huge probability. Then look at the remaining number and decide what to do next. If it is quite small (what "small" means is up to you) you could try a primality test (there is something in GMP i think) and if it gives it is a prime, you can in most of the cases trust it. Otherwise you have to factor it further.

If your numbers are really huge and you care about performance, then you definitely need to implement something more sophisticated than just a stupid division. Look at Quadratic Sieve (try wikipedia). It is quite simple but very powerful. If you are up to the chalenge, try MPQS, a variant of the quadratic sieve algorithm. [This forum](http://www.mersenneforum.org/) is a good source of information. There are even existing implementations of a tool you need - [see for example this](http://www.boo.net/~jasonp/qs.html).

Note though that numbers with 1k bits are huge by all means. Factoring such a number (even with MPQS or others) might take years if you are lucky and forever if not. I think that MPQS performs well with numbers of about 100-400 bits (if they are composed of two primes almost equally large, which is the hardest case of course).

Comment: for numbers with more than about 100 digits the Quadratic Sieve starts to get beaten by the General Number Field Sieve (GNFS).

Comment: @Chris Card - A 100 digits in which base?  Please specify.

Comment: In decimal base of course. Chris is right for such large numbers, QS (or to be clearer, MPQS, since QS is way slower with such numbers) starts to get slower than GNFS.

Comment: The current record factorisation is RSA768 (http://www.crypto-world.com/FactorRecords.html) which took a massive amount of work. It's possible to factor numbers with about 150 digits using GNFS on a standard modern PC, but 1k bits is out of reach at the moment to even the top researchers.

Comment: Yes, and any attempts on factoring huge numbers are most of the time done on distributed computer systems where each node contributes to the result with a small part. Even then it takes months or even years to finish the task.

Comment: You don't need to individually divide by small primes to weed them out. Simply take the product of all the small primes (this part is preprocessed), then compute a gcd.

Answer (score 6):

Below is a sample algorithm in Java (it's not C++ with GMP, but converting should be pretty straightforward) that:

1. generates a random number `x` of bitlength `Nbits`
2. tries to factor out all prime factors < 100, keeping a list of prime factors that divide x.
3. tests to see if the remaining factor is prime using Java's [`isProbablePrime`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime%28int%29) method
4. If the remaining factor product is prime with sufficient probability, we have succeeded in factoring x. (**STOP**)
5. Otherwise the remaining factor product is definitely composite (see the isProbablePrime docs).
6. While we still have time, we run the [Pollard rho algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) until we find a divisor d.
7. If we run out of time, we have failed. (**STOP**)
8. We have found a divisor d. So we factor out d, add the prime factors of d to the list of prime factors of x, and go to step 4.

All the parameters of this algorithm are near the beginning of the program listing. I looked for 1024-bit random numbers, with a timeout of 250 milliseconds, and I keep running the program until I get a number x with at least 4 prime factors (sometimes the program finds a number with 1, 2, or 3 prime factors first). With this parameter set, it usually takes about 15-20 seconds on my 2.66Ghz iMac.

Pollard's rho algorithm isn't really that efficient, but it's simple, compared to the [quadratic sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve) (QS) or the [general number field sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) (GNFS) -- I just wanted to see how the simple algorithm worked.

---

**Why this works:** (despite the claim of many of you that this is a hard problem)

The plain fact of it is, that [prime numbers aren't that rare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem). For 1024-bit numbers, the Prime Number Theorem says that about 1 in every 1024 ln 2 (= about 710)
numbers is prime.

So if I generate a random number x that is prime, and I accept probabilistic prime detection, I've successfully factored x.

If it's not prime, but I quickly factor out a few small factors, and the remaining factor is (probabilistically) prime, then I've successfully factored x.

Otherwise I just give up and generate a new random number. (which the OP says is acceptible)

Most of the numbers successfully factored will have 1 large prime factor and a few small prime factors.

The numbers that are hard to factor are the ones that have no small prime factors and at least 2 large prime factors (these include cryptographic keys that are the product of two large numbers; the OP has said nothing about cryptography), and I can just skip them when I run out of time.

```
package com.example;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class FindLargeRandomComposite {
    final static private int[] smallPrimes = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 
        31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 
        73, 79, 83, 89, 97};

    final static private int maxTime = 250;
    final static private int Nbits = 1024;
    final static private int minFactors = 4;
    final static private int NCERTAINTY = 4096;

    private interface Predicate { public boolean isTrue(); }

    static public void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        boolean found = false;
        BigInteger x=null;
        List<BigInteger> factors=null;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (!found)
        {
            x = new BigInteger(Nbits, r);
            factors = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
            Predicate keepRunning = new Predicate() {
                final private long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + maxTime;
                public boolean isTrue() {
                    return System.currentTimeMillis() < stopTime;
                }
            };
            found = factor(x, factors, keepRunning);
            System.out.println((found?(factors.size()+" factors "):"not factored ")+x+"= product: "+factors);
            if (factors.size() < minFactors)
                found = false;
        }
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Product verification: "+(x.equals(product(factors))?"passed":"failed"));
        System.out.println("elapsed time: "+(stopTime-startTime)+" msec");
    }

    private static BigInteger product(List<BigInteger> factors) {
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (BigInteger f : factors)
            result = result.multiply(f);
        return result;
    }

    private static BigInteger findFactor(BigInteger x, List<BigInteger> factors,
            BigInteger divisor)
    {
        BigInteger[] qr = x.divideAndRemainder(divisor);
        if (qr[1].equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
        {
            factors.add(divisor);
            return qr[0];
        }
        else
            return x;
    }

    private static BigInteger findRepeatedFactor(BigInteger x,
            List<BigInteger> factors, BigInteger p) {
        BigInteger xprev = null;
        while (xprev != x)
        {
            xprev = x;
            x = findFactor(x, factors, p);
        }
        return x;
    }

    private static BigInteger f(BigInteger x, BigInteger n)
    {
        return x.multiply(x).add(BigInteger.ONE).mod(n);
    }

    private static BigInteger gcd(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
        while (!b.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
        {
            BigInteger nextb = a.mod(b);
            a = b;
            b = nextb;
        }
        return a;
    }
    private static BigInteger tryPollardRho(BigInteger n,
            List<BigInteger> factors, Predicate keepRunning) {
        BigInteger x = new BigInteger("2");
        BigInteger y = x;
        BigInteger d = BigInteger.ONE;
        while (d.equals(BigInteger.ONE) && keepRunning.isTrue())
        {
            x = f(x,n);
            y = f(f(y,n),n);
            d = gcd(x.subtract(y).abs(), n);
        }
        if (d.equals(n))
            return x;
        BigInteger[] qr = n.divideAndRemainder(d);
        if (!qr[1].equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
            throw new IllegalStateException("Huh?");
        // d is a factor of x. But it may not be prime, so run it through the factoring algorithm.
        factor(d, factors, keepRunning);
        return qr[0];
    }

    private static boolean factor(BigInteger x0, List<BigInteger> factors,
            Predicate keepRunning) {

        BigInteger x = x0;
        for (int p0 : smallPrimes)
        {
            BigInteger p = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(p0));
            x = findRepeatedFactor(x, factors, p);          
        }
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done && keepRunning.isTrue())
        {
            done = x.equals(BigInteger.ONE) || x.isProbablePrime(NCERTAINTY);
            if (!done)
            {
                x = tryPollardRho(x, factors, keepRunning);
            }
        }
        if (!x.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
            factors.add(x);
        return done;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use Pollard p-1 factorization algorithm if the number you want to factor has small prime factors. It has factored out a 30 digit prime factor of the number 2 ^ 740 + 1. ECM is a similar but sub-exponetial algorithm but implementation is more difficult. The amount of time the algorithm is based on what the bound b is set as. It will factor any number which has a factor p where p - 1 is b-smooth.

```
//Pollard p - 1 factorization algorithm

void factor(mpz_t g, mpz_t n, long b)
{
    //sieve for primes
    std::vector<bool> r;

    for(int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        r.push_back(true);


    for(int i = 2; i < ceil(sqrt(b - 1)); i++)
        if(r.at(i) == true)
            for(int j = i * i; j < b; j += i)
                r.at(j) = false;

    std::vector<long> p;
    std::vector<long> a;
    for(int i = 2; i < b; i++)
        if(r[i] == true)
        {
            p.push_back(i);//Append the prime on to the vector
            int temp = floor(log(b) / log(i)); //temp = logb(i)

            // put primes in to sieve
            // a = the maximum power for p ^ a < bound b
            if(temp == 0)
                a.push_back(1);
            else
                a.push_back(temp);                
        }

    int m = p.size();//m = number of primes under bound b

    mpz_t c;// c is the number Which will be exponated
    mpz_init(c);
    long two = 2;
    mpz_set_ui(c, two);// set c to 2

    int z = 0;
    long x = 2;

    // loop c until a factor is found
    for(;;)
    {
    mpz_set_si( c, x);

    //powering ladder
    for(long i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for(long j = 0; j < a[i]; j++)
            mpz_powm_ui(c , c, (p[i]), n);

    //check if a factor has been found;
    mpz_sub_ui(c ,c,1);
    mpz_gcd(g ,c, n);
    mpz_add_ui(c , c, 1);

    //if g is a factor return else increment c
    if((mpz_cmp_si(g,1)) > 0 && (mpz_cmp(g,n)) < 0)
        return;
    else if (x > b)
        break;
    else
        x++;
    }

}


int main()
{
    mpz_t x;
    mpz_t g;

    //intialize g and x
    mpz_init(g);
    mpz_init_set_str(x,"167698757698757868925234234253423534235342655234234235342353423546435347",10);

    //p-1 will factor x as long as it has a factor p where p - 1 is b-smooth(has all prime factors less than bound b)
    factor(g , x, 1000);

    //output the factor, it will output 1 if algorithm fails
    mpz_out_str(NULL, 10, g);

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs - 7465647
Execution time - 0.003 seconds

Another Factoring algorithm created by J.Pollard was Pollards Rho algorithm which is not that quick but requires very little space. Their are also ways to parrelize it. Its complexity is O(n^1/4)

```
//Pollard rho factoring algorithm
void rho(mpz_t g, mpz_t n)
{
    mpz_t x;
    mpz_t y;
    mpz_init_set_ui(x ,2);
    mpz_init_set_ui(y ,2);//initialize x and y as 2
    mpz_set_ui(g , 1);
    mpz_t temp;
    mpz_init(temp);

    if(mpz_probab_prime_p(n,25) != 0)
        return;//test if n is prime with miller rabin test

    int count;
    int t1 = 0;
    int t2 = 1;
    int nextTerm = t1 + t2;
    while(mpz_cmp_ui(g,1) < 1)
    {
        f(x,n);//x is changed
        f(y,n);//y is going through the sequence twice as fast
        f(y,n);

        if(count == nextTerm)//calculate gcd every fibonacci number
        {
            mpz_sub(temp,x,y);
            mpz_gcd(g , temp, n);

            t1 = t2;
            t2 = nextTerm;
            nextTerm = t1 + t2;//calculate next fibonacci number
        }

        count ++;
    }

    return;
}

int main()
{
    mpz_t x;
    mpz_t g;

    //intialize g and x
    mpz_init(g);
    mpz_init_set_str(x,"167698757698757868925234234253423",10);


    rho(g , x);

    //output the factor, it will output 1 if algorithm fails
    mpz_out_str(NULL, 10, g);

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs - 353
Execution time - 0.003s

Comment: Where is the function `f()` from `f(x,n);`?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting task you have! Thanks!

It was a pleasure for me to spend two almost whole days to write very advanced solution. I implemented from scratch three factorization algorithms: [Trial Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division), [Pollard's Rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm), [Lenstra Elliptic Curve Method (ECM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization).

It is well known that ECM method (with elliptic curves) is one of the fastest methods for mid-range factors. While trial division is good for very small factors (up to 2^20 factor per second), Pollard Rho is good for bigger yet small factors (up to 2^40 per second), while ECM is good for mid-range factors (up to 2^60 per 10 seconds).

There are also very advanced methods like [General Number Field Sieve (GNFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) (factors up to 2^700 per month), but they are very difficult to implement. Also [Quadratic Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve) method is advanced (probably up to 2^400 per month), I also implemented this from sratch but it has very big code, yet manageable to understand, but due to its size I don't attach it here. ECM method was the only method quite easy to implement among advanced methods.

Besides mentioned above 3 methods of factorization that I implemented, I also used following algorithms inside code: [Modular Exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), [Fermat Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test), [Barrett Reduction](https://www.nayuki.io/page/barrett-reduction-algorithm), [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), [Modular Multiplicative Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), [Elliptic Curve Point Addition and Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication).

Actually your task as it is is very easy to solve fast: it is known that for bit size 2048 there appears a prime once approximately every `ln(2048) = 1420` number, so you just generate fast around 1500 numbers while checking if they are prime, for example using [Fermat Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test) which is very fast. And if a number is prime then by definition it is already factored as it is.

I extended in my mind your task further, to make it more interesting. I don't search for prime number, but instead trying to find such 2048-bit random-generated numbers such that they have at least several big prime factors. This kind of numbers I will call "interesting". Of course if a number has several tiny factors and one large prime then it is not that interesting. But if it has 60-bit prime factor then it is interesting to catch such number, that's what I do in my code.

You can see in my code that I adopted it for two kinds of libraries, [Boost Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) and [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). Both are included in my code (see `#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>` and `#include <gmpxx.h>`), so you should install and link both. Under Linux it is very easy to install both through `sudo apt install libboost-all-dev libgmp-dev`. But Windows is a bit tricky, install [Chocolatey Packet Manager](https://chocolatey.org/) first and then do command `choco install boost-msvc-14.3`. And for GMP install VCPKG as [described here](https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html) and then `vcpkg install gmp`. If you want you may install Boost through VCPKG too: `vcpkg install boost`.

ECM (elliptic curve) method is very interesting and simple:

1. You generate many random curves, with random X, Y, A, B, N params, where N is your input number that needs to be factored, and other params are random that fit curve equation `Y^2 = X^3 + A * x + B  (mod N)`.
2. You multiply each curve by all growing prime numbers (with some small power).
3. At some point you'll get a multiple of curve order for some first curve, and by a property of curve order in such a case you'll get so-called Infinite point on curve.
4. If you look at [Point Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication) formula then you may see that there is a denominator in formula `lambda = (y_q - y_p) / (x_q - x_p)`. This denominator is computed as [Modular Multiplicative Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) modulus N. For Infinite point it becomes non-invertible, and by property of inverse number non-invertibility is only possible when [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)(N, x_q - x_p) != 1, in which case GCD gives some non-trivial factor (sometimes also N), hence our N is factored successfully by giving first factor.
5. If we don't get Infinite point, then we continue to generate more curves and to divide by more (bigger and bigger) prime numbers. More curves we generate and more primes we multiply by, the higher is success of factorization.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/bjoM6Ehxs)

**SOURCE CODE HERE**. As StackOverflow has limit of 30K symbols per post and my code alone is about 44K bytes, I couldn't inline it here, but instead sharing it through Github Gist (link below). Also same code is above available through `Try it online!` link on GodBolt server.

[GitHub Gist code](https://gist.github.com/polkovnikov/f8e977eed9ccc121a027dbd650e26208)

Example console output:

```
TrialDiv time 8.230 sec
Num: 4343663370925180057127849780941698665126534031938076094687921681578209757551374613160773985436765755919464255163981465381983273353052491 (2^453.90)
Factored: 13 (2^3.70, prime), 167 (2^7.38, prime), 3853 (2^11.91, prime), 53831 (2^15.72, prime), 916471 (2^19.81, prime), 9255383 (2^23.14, prime), 
UnFactored: 11372390351822722497588418782148940973499109818654526670537593527638523385195910987808859992169924704037636069779 (2^372.24, composite), 
PollardRho time 8.51 sec
Num: 11372390351822722497588418782148940973499109818654526670537593527638523385195910987808859992169924704037636069779 (2^372.24)
Factored: 189379811 (2^27.50, prime), 2315962907 (2^31.11, prime), 50213994043 (2^35.55, prime), 
UnFactored: 5163708449171395447719565208770850251589387410889704005960043195676697732937073689 (2^278.09, composite), 
Curves   1, Ops   12.965 Ki, ExtraPrimes 512, Primes  0.500 Ki, IterTime   0.410 sec
Curves   2, Ops   50.912 Ki, ExtraPrimes 512, Primes  1.000 Ki, IterTime   8.062 sec
Curves   3, Ops  112.586 Ki, ExtraPrimes 464, Primes  1.453 Ki, IterTime  15.093 sec
Curves   4, Ops  162.931 Ki, ExtraPrimes 120, Primes  1.570 Ki, IterTime   4.853 sec
Curves   5, Ops  193.699 Ki, ExtraPrimes  80, Primes  1.648 Ki, IterTime   4.201 sec
ECM time 32.624 sec
Num: 5163708449171395447719565208770850251589387410889704005960043195676697732937073689 (2^278.09)
Factored: 955928964443 (2^39.80, prime), 
UnFactored: 540177004907359979630305557131905764121354872876442621652476639261690523 (2^238.29, composite), 
Final time 49.385 sec
Num: 4343663370925180057127849780941698665126534031938076094687921681578209757551374613160773985436765755919464255163981465381983273353052491 (2^453.90)
Factored: 13 (2^3.70, prime), 167 (2^7.38, prime), 3853 (2^11.91, prime), 53831 (2^15.72, prime), 916471 (2^19.81, prime), 9255383 (2^23.14, prime), 189379811 (2^27.50, prime), 2315962907 (2^31.11, prime), 50213994043 (2^35.55, prime), 955928964443 (2^39.80, prime), 
UnFactored: 540177004907359979630305557131905764121354872876442621652476639261690523 (2^238.29, composite),
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you cannot factor a bigint with GMP. You can convert your bigint to other libraries and use their factoring algorithms. Note that factoring of integers with >>20 digits needs specialized algorithms and is near exponentially slow.

Check out:

- http://flintlib.org/
- http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/
- http://ecm.gforge.inria.fr/