# simpler faster way to generate all possible length 1:n combinations of elements of a character vector of length n in R

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations, permutation, plyr

I'm trying to generate a dataframe or matrix of all possible unique combinations of lengths `1:n` for a character vector of length `n`. I've looked at [combn](https://rdrr.io/r/utils/combn.html), and `expand_grid` (see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705153/generate-list-of-all-possible-combinations-of-elements-of-vector)), and putting together approaches from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851327/convert-a-list-of-data-frames-into-one-data-frame), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/combine-two-data-frames-by-rows-rbind-when-they-have-different-sets-of-columns), have come up with a solution:

```
library(plyr)
char_vec <- c('a','b','c')
store <- list()
for (i in 1:length(char_vec)){
  store[[i]] <- as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(combn(char_vec, i, simplify = FALSE))))
}
df <- do.call("rbind.fill", store)
>df
  V1   V2   V3
1  a <NA> <NA>
2  b <NA> <NA>
3  c <NA> <NA>
4  a    b <NA>
5  a    c <NA>
6  b    c <NA>
7  a    b    c
>
```

This is my desired output; however, it is very slow with longer inputs, and strikes me as a clunky approach. Does anyone have any recommendations for speeding up and/or simplifying my solution?

Comment: See benchmarks in [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49591309/1851712) in the link.

Comment: Perfect. Missed it. Cheers.