# Get all level combinations for each group

Tags: r, combinations, expand

I have a list of customer IDs, each with a list of unique products they used. There can theoretically be up to ~150 unique products.

```
df <- tibble(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4),
             prod = c("Prod1", "Prod2", "Prod3", "Prod1", "Prod4", "Prod3", "Prod5", "Prod2"))
```

From that, I need to get all possible combinations of products for each ID, not only on the highest level (grouped by ID). That is, include the combination with all products, as expand_grid() would do, but also all combinations of *1,...,n* elements, where *n* is the number of unique products the ID has.

Final dataset should therefore look as such:

```
df_results <- tibble(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4),
                     combo = c("Prod1", "Prod2", "Prod3", "Prod1|Prod2", "Prod1|Prod3", "Prod2|Prod3", "Prod1|Prod2|Prod3",
                               "Prod1", "Prod4", "Prod1|Prod4",
                               "Prod3", "Prod5", "Prod3|Prod5",
                               "Prod2"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An extension of the [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953588/unordered-combinations-of-all-lengths):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  reframe(combo = as.character(do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(prod), \(m) combn(x = prod, m = m, FUN = \(x) paste(x, collapse = "|"))))))
```

```r
# A tibble: 14 × 2
      ID combo            
   <dbl> <chr>            
 1     1 Prod1            
 2     1 Prod2            
 3     1 Prod3            
 4     1 Prod1|Prod2      
 5     1 Prod1|Prod3      
 6     1 Prod2|Prod3      
 7     1 Prod1|Prod2|Prod3
 8     2 Prod1            
 9     2 Prod4            
10     2 Prod1|Prod4      
11     3 Prod3            
12     3 Prod5            
13     3 Prod3|Prod5      
14     4 Prod2
```

Or in base R:

```r
stack(tapply(df$prod, df$ID, 
       \(prod) do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(prod), \(m) combn(prod, m, FUN = \(x) paste(x, collapse = "|"))))))[2:1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `tidyverse` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 transmute(combo = map2(.x = list(prod), 
                        .y = seq_along(prod),
                        ~ combn(.x, .y, FUN = paste, collapse = "|"))) %>%
 unnest_longer(combo)

      ID combo            
   <dbl> <chr>            
 1     1 Prod1            
 2     1 Prod2            
 3     1 Prod3            
 4     1 Prod1|Prod2      
 5     1 Prod1|Prod3      
 6     1 Prod2|Prod3      
 7     1 Prod1|Prod2|Prod3
 8     2 Prod1            
 9     2 Prod4            
10     2 Prod1|Prod4      
11     3 Prod3            
12     3 Prod5            
13     3 Prod3|Prod5      
14     4 Prod2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R option using `intToBits` to map all combinations into binary presentation of integer indexing

```
with(
  df,
  setNames(
    rev(
      stack(
        by(
          Prod, ID,
          function(p) {
            sapply(
              seq(2^length(p) - 1),
              function(k) paste0(p[which(intToBits(k) > 0)], collapse = "|")
            )
          }
        )
      )
    ), names(df)
  )
)
```

which gives

```
   ID              Prod
1   1             Prod1
2   1             Prod2
3   1       Prod1|Prod2
4   1             Prod3
5   1       Prod1|Prod3
6   1       Prod2|Prod3
7   1 Prod1|Prod2|Prod3
8   2             Prod1
9   2             Prod4
10  2       Prod1|Prod4
11  3             Prod3
12  3             Prod5
13  3       Prod3|Prod5
14  4             Prod2
```

---

If you want to ***EXPLORE THE POSSIBILITY OF USING `expand.grid`*** (but NOT recommend it since it is rather **inefficient**), you can try the code below

```
with(
  df,
  setNames(
    rev(
      stack(
        lapply(
          split(Prod, ID),
          function(x) {
            unique(
              apply(
                expand.grid(rep(list(x), length(x))),
                1,
                function(v) {
                  paste0(sort(unique(v)), collapse = "|")
                }
              )
            )
          }
        )
      )
    ), names(df)
  )
)
```

which gives

```
   ID              Prod
1   1             Prod1
2   1       Prod1|Prod2
3   1       Prod1|Prod3
4   1 Prod1|Prod2|Prod3
5   1             Prod2
6   1       Prod2|Prod3
7   1             Prod3
8   2             Prod1
9   2       Prod1|Prod4
10  2             Prod4
11  3             Prod3
12  3       Prod3|Prod5
13  3             Prod5
14  4             Prod2
```