# Generate all possibles combinations of merged modalities

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to get all possibles combinations for a categorical variable, all stored in a vector.

As an example, let's take columns ("gear") of mtcars database. If the dedicated vector is named "all_combi" , the results should be as follows :

```
> mtcars$gear
 [1] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 4 6 
all_combi
[1] "3-4" "3-5" "4-5" "3-6" "3-4-6" "3-5-6" "3-6" "4-6" "5-6" "3-4-6"
```

I should have forgotten some combinations in the all_combi vector but I hope that you understood my question...
Thanks for you

Comment: [Are you looking for something like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953588/unordered-combinations-of-all-lengths/27953641#27953641)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <- c(4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6)
u <- sort(unique(x))
unlist(lapply(seq_along(u)[-1], \(m) combn(u, m, paste, collapse = "-")))
#>  [1] "3-4"     "3-5"     "3-6"     "4-5"     "4-6"     "5-6"     "3-4-5"   "3-4-6"   "3-5-6"   "4-5-6"   "3-4-5-6"
```

As noted in the comments, if speed is a concern, `RcppAlgos::comboGeneral` is faster than `combn`, and `Rfast::sort_unique(x)` is faster than `sort(unique(x))`.

Comment: `sort(unique(x))` is because the OP is starting with a larger vector of values with possible repeats. It's to show how to get to the unique sorted values generally. Yes, `seq_along(u)[-1]` would be safer. I'll update it along with a note that `RcppAlgos::comboGeneral` and `Rfast::sort_unique` are faster alternatives.