# How to Create Each Possible Pair in a matrix

Tags: r

I have a problem I'm not sure how to approach. I have a list of items in a matrix and I want to create a matrix that instead holds every possible combination of two of those items.

So say I have matrix_1 that looks Like this:

```
Matrix_1 <- as.matrix(a,b,c)

[,1]
A
B
C
```

From that I would like to Make A Matrix that looks as follows

```
[,1] [,2]
A A
A B
A C
B A
B B
B C
C A
C B
C C
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705153/generate-list-of-all-possible-combinations-of-elements-of-vector

Answer (score 5):

We can use `expand.grid`

```
as.matrix(expand.grid(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:3]))
```

--

Or using `crossing`

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(A1= LETTERS[1:3], B1 = LETTERS[1:3])
```

---

Or with `outer`

```
c(t(outer(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:3], paste0)))
#[1] "AA" "AB" "AC" "BA" "BB" "BC" "CA" "CB" "CC"
```

Comment: Can we use `combn`?

Comment: @NelsonGon  `combn` doesn't give the reverse combination, which I think the OP may need here `combn(LETTERS[1:3], 2)`