# R: Get all combinations of p binary variables

Tags: r

I would like to get a matrix that contains all $2^p$ combinations of $p$ binary variables. It feels like something that should be a one-liner but I can't seem to find this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found it:

```
p <- 3
l <- rep(list(0:1), p)
expand.grid(l)
```

From here:
[Generate list of all possible combinations of elements of vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705153/generate-list-of-all-possible-combinations-of-elements-of-vector)