# How do I select a combination of two variables from a dataframe when each variable value can only be selected once?

Tags: r, algorithm, performance, igraph, combinatorics

I have a data frame similar to

```
 TheDF <- data.frame(VarA=rep(c(7, 8, 11, 14), 4), Var2=c(1,1,1,0, 0,2,2,0, 0,0,3,0, 0,0,4,4), 
                Var3=c(50, 50, 50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 150, 150, 150, 150, 200, 200, 200, 200))
 TheDF <- TheDF %>%
    filter(Var2>0)
```

I need a solution that selects the combination of rows such that each value of `Var1` and `Var2` can only be selected once.

The result would look like (in this case there is only one solution)

```
 Var1      Var2
 7          1
 8          2
 11         3
 14         4
```

This is for any number of `Var1` and `Var2`. If there is a non-unique solution such as:

```
 TheDF2 <- data.frame(VarA=rep(c(7, 8, 11, 14), 5), Var2=c(1,1,1,0, 0,2,2,0, 0,0,3,0, 0,0,4,4, 0,0,5,5), 
                Var3=c(50, 50, 50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 150, 150, 150, 150, 200, 200, 200, 200, 250, 250, 250, 250))
TheDF2 <- TheDF2 %>%
   filter(Var2>0)
```

where `Var2` values of both 4 and 5 can satisfy the requirement for uniqueness, the selected result should be based on `Var3`. The selected `Var2` value would be 5, because the `Var3` value for 5 is 250, compared to 200 for `Var4`, giving:

```
 Var1   Var2
 7      1
 8      2
 11     3
 14     5
```

If both `Var3` values were the same, it would be a random choice.

If it was impossible to get a unique solution for one pair, then just return the ones that were unique. E.g.

```
 TheDF3 <- data.frame(VarA=rep(c(7, 8, 11, 14), 4), Var2=c(1,0,0,0, 0,2,2,0, 3,0,0,0, 0,0,0,4), 
                 Var3=c(50, 50, 50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 150, 150, 150, 150, 200, 200, 200, 200))
TheDF3 <- TheDF3 %>%
  filter(Var2>0)
```

One solution would be, using the `Var3` weights:

```
 Var1    Var2
 7       3
 8       2
 14      4
```

The other possible solution is:

```
 Var1     Var2
 7        3
 11       2
 14       4
```

because the sum of the weights for both solutions is the same.

Edit: I am now leaning towards a solution similar to [combination method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705153/generate-list-of-all-possible-combinations-of-elements-of-vector) to get every combination of `Var1` and `Var2`, with the value of `Var1` as the column headings and the value of `Var2` as the cell values. With a new variable as the sum of the `Var3` in the row, and another new variable that counts the number of duplicates in the row. I don't know how to implement this either.

In the current example I am working on IRL, the number of combinations is 15,972.

Edit 2: desired combination output would look like (using DF1):

```
        7    8    11   14     Duplicates   Weight
 [1]    1    1    1    4      2            350
 [2]    1    1    2    4      1            400
 [3]    1    1    3    4      1            450
 [4]    1    1    4    4      2            500
 [5]    1    2    1    4      1            400
 ...
 [n]    1    2    4    4      1            550
```

with `VarA` turning into the column headers, and each row is each combination of `Var2` values. `Duplicates` is the number of duplicated `Var2` values in the row, and weight is the sum of the weight for each `Var2` given the `VarA` value. In the simple example I gave, all the weights within a `Var2` value are the same. In reality, the weights differ. For example, for `Var2` 2, the `Var3` values might be 120 if `VarA` = 8 and 245 if `Var4` = 11.

In my use case, `Var1` is age, `Var2` is school, and `Var3` is the roll count for that school for that age.

Comment: Where do you get 13 from?

Comment: Example 1 only has four values for Var2, the second example has five values (which is where the weights come in). So far, without using a complicated optimiser, I was thinking maybe of combining every possible combination of the Var1 and Var2 values, summing the weights, and counting the number of duplicate values for Var2. The solution is then the one with the smallest number of duplicates, with the largest number of weights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem can be interpreted as a [max bipartite matching](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/matching.pdf) problem, so you can use `max_bipartite_match` from `igraph` package to solve it

```
library(igraph)
f <- function(df) {
    # generate bipartite match
    g <- graph_from_data_frame(df) %>%
        set_vertex_attr(name = "type", value = names(V(.)) %in% df$VarA)
    # max bipartite match
    bm <- na.omit(max_bipartite_match(g)$matching)
    # retrieve match pattern and yield output
    v1 <- bm[bm %in% df$VarA]
    v2 <- names(v1)
    data.frame(
        Var1 = `class<-`(v1, class(df$VarA)),
        Var2 = `class<-`(v2, class(df$Var2))
    )
}
```

and you will see the output (as per your input `TheDF`, `TheDF2` and `TheDF3`)

```
> f(TheDF)
  Var1 Var2
1    7    1
2    8    2
3   11    3
4   14    4

> f(TheDF2)
  Var1 Var2
1    7    1
2    8    2
3   11    3
4   14    4

> f(TheDF3)
  Var1 Var2
1    7    1
2    8    2
3   14    4
```