# R - Add combinations of elements within a vector

Tags: r, vector

Does anyone know of a way to add up combinations of numbers within a vector?

Suppose I am going through a for loop and each time I end up with a vector of different lengths, how could I combine each element of this vector such that I have the sum of 2, 3, etc elements?

For example if I have:

```
vector <- c(1:5)
```

And want to go through it as in:

```
element 1 + element 2; element 2 + element 3, etc
```

But also:

```
element 1 + element 2 + element 3
```

How would I do this? It's important to note that in many of the vectors the lengths will be different. So whilst one vector might contain 3 elements another might contain 12.

I know you can do `vector[1]+vector[2]`, but I need some way to iterate throughout the vector wherein it takes into account the above note.

Answer (score 3):

Use you can use `combn`:

```
> combn(vector, 3, FUN = NULL, simplify = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    2    2     3
[2,]    2    2    2    3    3    4    3    3    4     4
[3,]    3    4    5    4    5    5    4    5    5     5
```

The trick here is that each call will return a matrix of results, and you will have to decide how you want to aggregate and store all the various combinations.

If you don't mind having a list, then the following should do the trick:

```
> sapply(c(1:length(vector)),
         function(x) {
             combn(vector, x, FUN = NULL, simplify = TRUE)
         })
```

Answer (score 3):

## Generate pair IDs

In this case, we need to get the pairs:

```
combn(3, 2)
```

**Output:**

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    2
[2,]    2    3    3
```

Pairs are generated by column.

## Sum Over Vector Elements (Using a Subset)

To access each element and perform a summation, we opt to define a helper function that takes the combination and the vector.

```
# Write a helper function 
# sums of the index of the vector
comb_subset_sum = function(x, vec){
  return(sum(vec[x]))
}
```

From this, we can use `combn` directly or use `sapply`.

### Summing for 1 *k*:

`combn` directly:

```
# Input Vector
vec = 1:5

# Length of vector
n = length(vec)

# Generate pairwise combinations and obtain pair_sum
# Specify the k (m in R)
m = combn(n, m = 2, FUN = comb_subset_sum, vec = vec)
```

`sapply` usage:

```
# Input Vector
vec = 1:5

# Number of Observations
n = length(vec)

# Combinations
# Specify the k (m in R)
combinations = combn(n, m = 2)

# Obtain vectorized sum over subset
subset_summed = apply(combinations, 2, comb_subset_sum, vec = vec)
```

Example Output:

**combinations**:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3     4
[2,]    2    3    4    5    3    4    5    4    5     5
```

**subset_summed**:

```
 [1] 3 4 5 6 5 6 7 7 8 9
```

Trace:

```
vec[1]+vec[2]=3 
vec[1]+vec[3]=4 
vec[1]+vec[4]=5 
vec[1]+vec[5]=6 
vec[2]+vec[3]=5 
vec[2]+vec[4]=6 
vec[2]+vec[5]=7 
vec[3]+vec[4]=7 
vec[3]+vec[5]=8 
vec[4]+vec[5]=9
```

To obtain the trace output, add the following before `return()` in `comb_subset_sum()`:

```
cat(paste0("vec[",x,"]", collapse = "+"), "=", sum(vec[x]), "\n")
```

### Summing for multiple *k*:

Here, we apply the same logic, just in a way that enables the *k* value of the combination to take multiple values.

```
# Input Vector
vec = 1:5

# Length of Vec
n = length(vec)

# Store output
o = vector('list',n)

for(i in seq_along(vec)){
  o[[i]] = combn(n, i, FUN = comb_subset_sum, vec = vec)
}
```

**Note:** The size of each element of `o` will vary as the number of combinations will increase and then decrease.

## Summing over combinations

If we do not care about vector element values, we can then just sum over the actual combinations in a similar way to how we obtained the vector elements.

To generate pairs and then sum, use:

```
# Input Vector
vec = 1:5

# Length of Vec
n = length(vec)

# Generate all combinations (by column)
# Specify the k (m in R)
m = combn(n, m = 2)

# Obtain sum by going over columns
sum_m = apply(m, 2, sum)
```

Or do it in one go:

```
# Specify the k (m in R)
sum_inplace = combn(n, m = 2, FUN = sum)
```

Equality:

```
all.equal(sum_m,sum_inplace)
```

### Sum over *k* uses

And, as before, we can set it up to get all sums under different *k* by using:

```
# Input Vector
vec = 1:5

# Length of Vec
n = length(vec)

# Store output (varying lengths)
o = vector('list',n)

for(i in seq_along(vec)){
  o[[i]] = combn(n, i, FUN = sum)
}
```

Comment: Hi. I don't really understand your answer. In the example in my question the maximum possible value would be 15 (5+4+3+2+1) but when I run your code I get some values as high as 40. I just need some way to add up all the different combinations of elements within a vector, but in a for loop wherein the vector have x number of elements. Perhaps I have misunderstood?

Comment: Consider `C(5,3)` via `choose(5,3)` this gives a total number of combinations of 10. Thus, for each of those combinations, we get a different `vec` element IDs. We use those element ID to obtain a subset in `vec` and then `sum` over it. Thus, for `C(5,3)` we should have a `numeric` vector of length `10` that contains 10 distinct vector sums.

Comment: See the additional trace information @Gotmadstacks for clarification as to what the first bit is doing.

Answer (score 1):

The following relies on the binary representation of number. Basically, you have 2^n combinations to check. By writing any number between 1 and 2^n in binary with 'n' bits, you have all the permutations of elements you might want.

The `number2binary` function comes from Paul Hiestra's answer in this tread: [How to convert integer number into binary vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088080/how-to-convert-number-into-binary-vector)

```
number2binary = function(number, noBits) {
  binary_vector = rev(as.numeric(intToBits(number)))
  if(missing(noBits)) {
    return(binary_vector)
  } else {
    binary_vector[-(1:(length(binary_vector) - noBits))]
  }
}

vector <- 1:5

n <- length(vector)

comp_sum <- function(x) {
  binary <- number2binary(x, noBits = n)
  result <- sum(vector[which(binary==1)])
  names(result) <- paste(which(binary == 1), collapse = "+")
  return(result)
}

binaries <- sapply(1:2^n-1, comp_sum)
```

Note: I only go up to 2^n - 1 as you do not need the "zero". By adding some conditions in your `comp_sum` function, you can pick only sums of two elements or of three elements...

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `rollsum` from `zoo` package, where you can specify the number of elements you want to add up:

```
lapply(2:5, function(i) zoo::rollsum(1:5, i))
[[1]]
[1] 3 5 7 9    # two elements roll sum

[[2]]
[1]  6  9 12   # three elements roll sum

[[3]]
[1] 10 14      # four elements roll sum

[[4]]
[1] 15         # five elements roll sum
```