# Binary encoding in R

Tags: r, encoding, binary, analytics

I want to convert a set of categorical values to binary in R. The number of variables may not be fixed.
[An Example of my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl3qu.png)

I am able to convert it into numeric values using the function "as.numeric". Dont know how to proceed further. Please Help

[My final output should look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYyaZ.png)

It is for XGBoost

Thanks in Advance.

A Newbie Here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088080/how-to-convert-integer-number-into-binary-vector should help you out!

Comment: did the above link help?

Comment: Yes Joel. I used "inttobin" to convert it into string. Next thing I want is to split this into 3 different columns(should be scalable to any number of strings)

Comment: can't help without you adding a sample data in the question. Share the `dput(data.frame)` result here

Comment: how can I share the data here in the comment

Comment: if the link shared doesn't help , then lets ask a new question with what you need..

Comment: I have edited the question. You should be able to see the changes.

Comment: no one answer this question since it has been locked... ask a new question