# How do I Compute Binary String Permutations in R?

Tags: r, string, binary, permutation

I have a binary string like this:

```
0010000
```

I'd like to have all these permutations:

```
1010000
0110000
0011000
0010100
0010010
0010001
```

Is there anybody know which function in R could give me these results?

Comment: This is really `bitwOr(16, 2^(0:6))`, though that prints in decimal

Comment: To follow up the post by @alistaire , we can use any of the answers found here [How to convert an integer to number into binary vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12088080/4408538) such as `sapply(bitwOr(16, 2^(0:6)),function(x){ as.integer(intToBits(x))})` and you can slice and dice it however you'd like after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R has functions for bitwise operations, so we can get the desired numbers with `bitwOr`:

```r
bitwOr(16, 2^(6:0))
#> [1] 80 48 16 24 20 18 17
```

...or if we want to exclude the original,

```r
setdiff(bitwOr(16, 2^(6:0)), 16)
#> [1] 80 48 24 20 18 17
```

However, it only works in decimal, not binary. That's ok, though; we can build some conversion functions:

```r
bin_to_int <- function(bin){
    vapply(strsplit(bin, ''), 
           function(x){sum(as.integer(x) * 2 ^ seq(length(x) - 1, 0))}, 
           numeric(1))
}

int_to_bin <- function(int, bits = 32){
    vapply(int, 
           function(x){paste(as.integer(rev(head(intToBits(x), bits))), collapse = '')},
           character(1))
}
```

Now:

```r
input <- bin_to_int('0010000')

output <- setdiff(bitwOr(input, 2^(6:0)),
                  input)

output
#> [1] 80 48 24 20 18 17

int_to_bin(output, bits = 7)
#> [1] "1010000" "0110000" "0011000" "0010100" "0010010" "0010001"
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that the problem is to successively replace each 0 in the input with a 1 for an input string of 0's and 1's.

Replace each character successively with a `"1"`, regardless of its value and then remove any components of the result equal to the input.  No packages are used.

```
input <- "0010000"

setdiff(sapply(1:nchar(input), function(i) `substr<-`(input, i, i, "1")), input)
## [1] "1010000" "0110000" "0011000" "0010100" "0010010" "0010001"
```

**Update:** Have completely revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)   
bin <- '0010000'
ones <- str_locate_all(bin, '1')[[1]][,1]
zeros <- (1:str_length(bin))[-ones]
sapply(zeros, function(x){
str_sub(bin, x, x) <- '1'
bin
})
[1] "1010000" "0110000" "0011000" "0010100" "0010010" "0010001"
```