# R: all possible combinations of a binary vector of length n, where only one value is “1” in each combination of m

Tags: r, combinations, combinatorics

Is there a way in R to create binary sets of m, filled with all combinations of n by columns, while by row *only* 1 value can be "1"?

For example, for n=2 and m=2, we would have the following combinations of m each:

```
(00, 00), (10,00), (01,00), (00,10), (00,01), (10,01), (01,10), (10,10), (01,01)
```

But these, for example, are *not* allowed:
    (11,00), (01,11), (00,11), (11,10), (11,11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48292795/4408538). In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48307636/4408538) to that question, we see that rephrasing the question, makes it much easier to attack. So for this question, we can reduce it to: *"How to generate all pairwise permutations of powers of 2 **with repeats**?"*

We can use almost exactly the same setup as before, only this time we set the argument `repeats.allowed = TRUE`.

```
library(gtools)
bitPairwise2 <- function(numBits, groupSize) {
  t(sapply(t(permutations(numBits + 1, groupSize, 
                           c(0, 2^(0:(numBits-1))), repeats.allowed = TRUE)), 
           function(x) {as.integer(intToBits(x))})[1:numBits, ])
}

bitPairwise2(2,2)
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    0    0    ## (00,00)
 [2,]    0    0

 [3,]    0    0    ## (00,10)
 [4,]    1    0

 [5,]    0    0    ## (00,01)
 [6,]    0    1

 [7,]    1    0    ## (10,00)
 [8,]    0    0

 [9,]    1    0    ## (10,10)
[10,]    1    0

[11,]    1    0    ## (10,01)
[12,]    0    1
```

This function generalizes to any number of bits as well as any number of groups. For example, all possible 3-tuples of 3 bits is given by:

```
## first 9 groups
bitPairwise2(3, 3)[1:27, ]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    0    0    0    ## (000,000,000)
 [2,]    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0

 [4,]    0    0    0    ## (000,000,100)
 [5,]    0    0    0
 [6,]    1    0    0

 [7,]    0    0    0    ## (000,000,010)
 [8,]    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    1    0

[10,]    0    0    0    ## (000,000,001)
[11,]    0    0    0
[12,]    0    0    1

[13,]    0    0    0    ## (000,100,000)
[14,]    1    0    0
[15,]    0    0    0

[16,]    0    0    0    ## (000,100,100)
[17,]    1    0    0
[18,]    1    0    0

[19,]    0    0    0    ## (000,100,010)
[20,]    1    0    0
[21,]    0    1    0

[22,]    0    0    0    ## (000,100,001)
[23,]    1    0    0
[24,]    0    0    1

[25,]    0    0    0    ## (000,010,000)
[26,]    0    1    0
[27,]    0    0    0
```

And here are the last 9 groups:

```
a <- bitPairwise2(3, 3)[166:192, ]
row.names(a) <- 166:192
a
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
166    0    0    1    ## (001,100,001)
167    1    0    0
168    0    0    1

169    0    0    1    ## (001,010,000)
170    0    1    0
171    0    0    0

172    0    0    1    ## (001,010,100)
173    0    1    0
174    1    0    0

175    0    0    1    ## (001,010,010)
176    0    1    0
177    0    1    0

178    0    0    1    ## (001,010,001)
179    0    1    0
180    0    0    1

181    0    0    1    ## (001,001,000)
182    0    0    1
183    0    0    0

184    0    0    1    ## (001,001,100)
185    0    0    1
186    1    0    0

187    0    0    1    ## (001,001,010)
188    0    0    1
189    0    1    0

190    0    0    1    ## (001,001,001)
191    0    0    1
192    0    0    1
```

If you need the output in a list, try this:

```
test <- bitPairwise2(4, 3)
numGroups <- nrow(test)/3

makeGroupList <- function(mat, nG, groupSize) {
    lapply(1:nG, function(x) {
        s <- groupSize*(x-1) + 1
        e <- s + (groupSize - 1)
        mat[s:e, ]
    })
}

makeGroupList(test, numGroups, 3)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0    0    0

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0

 .      .    .    .    .
 .      .    .    .    .
 .      .    .    .    .
```

Comment: I am in awe. Thank you so much Joseph, and for your amazing explanation.

Comment: Just one last question, I get an error when using e.g. bitPairwise2(109, 3) - Error in sapply(t(permutations(numBits + 1, groupSize, c(0, 2^(0:(numBits -  subscript out of bounds, is this because of R limits? Can it not work when the combinations are this great? Thanks again.

Comment: @user971102 After you get the error, you should also get the message `In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)`. If you type `warnings()`, you will see `In intToBits(x) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range`. This happens because the vector `c(0, 2^(0:(numBits - 1))` with `numBits = 109` will have a maximal element of `2^108 = 3.245186e+32`. This is way to big for `intToBit` to work on (it only accepts integers (max = `2^31 - 1`)).  You will need a different approach to work on problems of this size.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!!