# R: Confusion With Binary Conversion

Tags: r

I am trying to learn how to convert numbers to binary and back in R.

Suppose I have the following binary string:

```
binary_string = "1101000011000001"
```

I know how to convert this into base 10:

```
base::strtoi(binary_string, base = 2)
[1] 53441
```

**Now, I am trying to learn how to convert 53441 back into binary**

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088080/how-to-convert-integer-number-into-binary-vector
number2binary = function(number, noBits) {
    binary_vector = rev(as.numeric(intToBits(number)))
    if(missing(noBits)) {
        return(binary_vector)
    } else {
        binary_vector[-(1:(length(binary_vector) - noBits))]
    }
}

> number2binary(53441)
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1

paste0(number2binary(53441), collapse="")
```

[image]

**My Question:** Am I doing this correctly?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.html

Comment: It's giving you the correct answer, is it not? What exactly is the question here?

Comment: @ Guy Incognito: thank you for your reply! I just wanted to make sure I was doing this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **you are doing right**. Also, you can try

```
trimws(
  paste0(rev(as.integer(intToBits(53441))), collapse = ""), 
  "left", 
  "0"
)
```

which gives

```
"1101000011000001"
```

Comment: @ Thank you so much for your answer! I can also use this function to do the opposite? base::strtoi(binary_string, base = 2)