# Writing a function to calculate divisors in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a simple function in R to calculate all divisors of a number. 
That is how I want to have my output:

```
> divisors(21)
[1] 1 3 7 21
```

I am a beginner and started with the code below. However I think it is completely wrong since it does not work at all.

```
divisors <- function(number) {
  x <- c(1:number)
  for(i in 1:number){
    if(number/i == c(x)) {
      paste(i)
    }
  }
  return(i)
}
divisors(10)
```

Comment: So you do _not_ want only the prime factorizaton, right? Really you should do more searching.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this...

```
divisors <- function(x){
  #  Vector of numberes to test against
  y <- seq_len(x)
  #  Modulo division. If remainder is 0 that number is a divisor of x so return it
  y[ x%%y == 0 ]
}

divisors(21)
#[1]  1  3  7 21

divisors(4096)
#[1]    1    2    4    8   16   32   64  128  256  512 1024 2048
```

Of course, with larger numbers efficiency gets more important. You might want to replace `seq_len(x)` with something like...

```
seq_len( ceiling( x / 2 ) )
```

And this is only designed to work with positive natural numbers.

#### Update: An aside using Rcpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
//[[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector divCpp( int x ){
  IntegerVector divs = seq_len( x / 2 );
  IntegerVector out(0);
  for( int i = 0 ; i < divs.size(); i++){
    if( x % divs[i] == 0 )
      out.push_back( divs[i] );
  }
  return out;
}
```

Gives the same results:

```
identical( divCpp( 1e6 ) , divisors( 1e6 ) )
#[1] TRUE
```

Run against the base R function...

```
require( microbenchmark )
bm <- microbenchmark( divisors(1e6) , divCpp(1e6) )
print( bm , unit = "relative" , digits = 3 , order = "median" )

#Unit: relative
#            expr  min   lq median   uq  max neval
#   divCpp(1e+06) 1.00 1.00   1.00 1.00  1.0   100
# divisors(1e+06) 8.53 8.73   8.55 8.41 11.3   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Or  `gmp::factorize` , among other existing tools.

I often find it handy to look at the source for released packages to get good ideas for doing similar tasks.

Comment: *surely* more of a comment?

Comment: @SimonO101 well, it was short, but it is an answer .  It's a fine line....

Comment: Yeah true. I was taking a look at your website. There is interest!! nice set of pinball machines :-)

Comment: This does not give the factors of a number, only the prime factorization. E.G. for n = 75600, factorize(n) returns 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 5 5 7, when there are over 100 factors/divisors.

Comment: @JosephWood OTOH, once you have the prime factorization it's just a matter of creating all combinations of same, which is trivially easy with standard R tools.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, trivial is all relative.  Sure, given the prime factorization of a number *d*, I can brutishly write a one-liner that will get the job done like so (gmp and gtools):

sort(unique(c(1,unlist(sapply(1:length(d), function(x) apply(combinations(length(d),x), 1, function(y) prod(d[y])))))))

However, I wouldn't want to call this more than a few times.  I think many would agree that more elegant solutions such a the one provided by [Richie Cotton](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6425726/4408538) is non-trivial.

Comment: I just realized, I linked the wrong answer.  Here is the correct [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6425597/4408538) to the answer provided by Richie Cotton.