# R: Return prime factors along with exponents

Tags: r, primes, factorization

Is there a way in R to obtain the prime factorization of a given number *n* that shows the prime factors along with their corresponding exponents?

For example, if the output was two vectors, the first would contain the prime factors of *n* and the second would contain the corresponding exponents.

just to give an example if n=123456

the first vector should be

2 3 643

the second one

6 1 1

as 123456 = 2^6x3^1x643^1
Thanks in advance for any help

piero

Answer (score 3):

Using package `numbers`:

```
library(numbers)

fs = primeFactors(152)
# Prime factor vector:
unique(fs)
# Vector with exponents:
as.vector(table(fs))
```

Answer (score 3):

I came across this in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6425597/4408538) provided by [Richie Cotton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134830/richie-cotton) for factoring numbers.  With `gmp` and `plyr` we have:

```
> library(gmp)
> library(plyr)
> b <- count(asNumeric(factorize(123456)))
> b
    x freq
1   2    6
2   3    1
3 643    1

> b$x
[1]   2   3 643

> b$freq
[1] 6 1 1
```

The `gmp` package can handle much larger numbers than the `numbers` package. Another advantage of this setup is that all of the information is stored in one object (i.e. in `b` above there is no need to call further functions to obtain what you are looking for, simply subset `b`).

Comment: Nice. Here's a way without ``plyr``: ``table(as.numeric(factorize(123456)))`` (which seems to work well enough)