# Filtering a numerical vector in R (vs Python as a list)

Tags: python, r, function, methods

I'm trying to learn about R; I was writing a function to return the (proper) divisors of a number.
In Python I can use the filter method, like this:

```
def divisors(n):
    numbers = list(range(1,n))
    an_iterator = filter(lambda x: n % x ==0, numbers)
    return(list(an_iterator))
```

What is a good way to write that sort of function, this time working with a vector in R? So far I have this:

```
divisors <- function(n){
  vec <- 1:(n-1)
  vec <- ifelse(n %% vec == 0, vec, FALSE)
  vec <- vec[vec!=FALSE]
  return(vec)
}
```

EDIT: I also found from below the "which()" function:

```
divisors <- function(n) {
  vec <- 1:(n-1)
  vec <- vec[which(n %% vec == 0)]
  return(vec)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Function for returning ALL factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424856/r-function-for-returning-all-factors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the best way is to take advantage of R's *vector* approach, that can be thought of as a very efficient *for* loop. For example:

```
divisors = function (n) {
  div = 1:(n - 1)
  div[n %% div == 0]
}
```

(note: i use the `=` operator to assign, that is not a common practice in R where the `<-` is by far more common. I use it here because is resembles the way assignments are made in other languages, including Python)

Here `div = 1:(1 - n)` will create a *vector* of possible divisors. `n %% div` will return the *remainder* for `n / div` in the form of a *vector* of the same length as `div`. This is as if we had made a for loop ranging through each element of `div` and concatenating every result. This is what people refer to as *vectorization* in R, this process is written in C and really efficient. The last bit is subsetting (filter) `div` to get only the proper divisors. Again i use here the *vector* approach, an generate a logical vector with `n %% div == 0`. Subsetting with this will return only those values from `div` for which the condition holds, so

```
> divisors(26)
[1]  1  2 13
```

Best,

Comment: Better to use `seq_len(n - 1)`.  With yours, `divisors(1)` gives `c(1, NA)`.

Comment: Good point! `seq_len()` will also complain if `n < 0`. It will still fail in case `n == 0`. I think the goal here is to illustrate how R can handle the task, a fail-proof function will need some extra thoughts and test.

Comment: I agree, you're not trying to make it bulletproof, but in R you should rarely use `1:n`.  It should be general practice to use `seq_len(n)`, and then weird bugs won't catch you later.

Answer (score 2):

Many functions in R work very well by default with vectors, so for example if you evaluate `6 %% 1:6` you will get `0 0 0 2 1 0`. All of the 0s represent where 6 was divided into evenly. Since you want the actual numbers that divided evenly, not the result, you want to compare the results to 0, or ask `0 0 0 2 1 0 == 0` which will return `TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE`. With this result you can index your original vector to return the correct subset `(1:6)[(6 %% 1:6) == 0]` however since the indices themselves indicate the correct subset in our case I used the R function `which` that returns the indices for `TRUE` values in a vector.

Also to find the proper divisors you only need to go up to half of the value you are investigating. The `floor` function ensures the result is an integer for odd numbers.

```
divisors <- function(n) {
    which((n %% 1:floor(n / 2)) == 0)
}
```

Comment: I couldn't parse that, but I did write a function using which. I'll add it to the original post.

Comment: `1:floor(n / 2)` makes a vector from 1 to half of n since past half there won't be any proper divisors. Then `n %%` that vector takes n and mods each number in the vector you created. `== 0` compares all the results to 0 and returns TRUE for every slot in the vector where 0 is and FALSE otherwise. `which` returns the index of where the result was TRUE which are the proper divisors.

Comment: Thanks, edited answer to remove extra `]` at the end of 2nd line.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain how this code answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues.